# How do find smallest file size in s3 bucket using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to get min/max of file size in S3 bucket and I always get 3 values instead of one.
I think it's controlled by pagination but I'm unable to disable it.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 
--bucket my-bucket-dev 
--prefix subscription/2019/04/01/23 
--output text  
--query 'sort_by(Contents,&Size)[:1].Size'
```

Result:

```
618
616
620
```

How do i get `616` as result without the need to sort locally?

> NOTE: I tried sort(), min(), max() max_by(), --no-pagination,
>   --page-size 100000
>
> they all give at least 3 records as result.

Comment: `--query` gets locally evaluated, so your current approach does already sort locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --query 'sort_by(Contents,&Size)[0].Size'
```

The `sort_by()` sorts by size, so you just want the first element by using `[0]`.

Comment: it still gives 3 values if `--output text`

Comment: That is very strange! Try putting an extra `/` at the end of your `prefix` to indicate that it is a folder rather than a partial filename. Or, try it without a `prefix` to see whether it gives a single number. To try and figure out what is happening, output the `Key` instead of the `Size` so you can figure out where those 3 objects are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

once i put `--output json` instead of `--output text` it gave me min size.

```
[
    616
]
```

another good point about local --query from @Dunedan - it looks like internaly it retrieves all files and applies sort_by() locally (so I'm paying for it - there are no cost savings vs other methods)

Answer (score 1):

I know that OP explicitly said

> [...] without the need to sort locally

But in case anyone was interested, I personally find the following more readable:

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir/ --recursive | sort -k 3 -n -r | (head -n 1 && tail -n 1)
```

---

**PS**:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir/ --recursive --human-readable
```

to make the result more readable